# How to retrieve values from from a table with Foreign Keys in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I'm a bit new to Java and Spring and I have encountered a problem while trying to complete an assignment for a course I'm following.

What I had to do was to create a online shop in Spring MVC while connecting the web app to a MySQL database - the first JSP with **Clients** where I would have the options to *display, add, delete and modify* clients - the second JSP with **Products** having the same options available(display, add, delete and modify) - and the last JSP with **Sales** or Transactions.

***The Models/Beans***

public class **Client** {

```
private int clientID;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String address;
private String city;
private String country;       

public Client(){
}

public Client(int clientId){
    this.clientID=clientId;
}

public int getClientID() {
    return clientID;
}

public void setClientID(int clientID) {
    this.clientID = clientID;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
```

}

public class **Sale** {

```
private int saleId;
private Client client_id;
private Product productId;

public Sale() {
}          

public int getSaleId() {
    return saleId;
}

public void setSaleId(int saleId) {
    this.saleId = saleId;
}

public Client getClientId() {
    return client_id;
}

public void setClientId(Client client_id) {
    this.client_id = client_id;
}

public Product getProductId() {
    return productId;
}

public void setProductId(Product productId) {
    this.productId = productId;
}
```

}

public class **Product** {

```
private int productId;
private String productName;
private double unitPrice;
private String description;
private long unitsInStock; 

public Product(){}

public Product(int productId){
    this.productId=productId;
}

public int getProductID() {
    return productId;
}

public void setProductID(int productId) {
    this.productId = productId;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

public double getUnitPrice() {
    return unitPrice;
}

public void setUnitPrice(double unitPrice) {
    this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public long getUnitsInStock() {
    return unitsInStock;
}

public void setUnitsInStock(long unitsInStock) {
    this.unitsInStock = unitsInStock;
}
```

}

The problem is in SaleDAO.java class where the getSales() method does not allow me to retrieve the values from the db.

The *clients* table has clientId(PK), firstname, lastname, address, city, country as rows.
*products* - productId(PK), productName, unitPrice, description and unitsInStock
*sales* - saleId(PK), client_id(FK) related to clients (clientId), product_id(FK) related to products (productId).

public class ***SaleDAO*** {

```
private final Connection conn;

public SaleDAO() {

    conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
}

public void addSale(Sale sale) {
    try {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO sales(saleId, client_id, product_id) VALUES (?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setInt(1, sale.getSaleId());
        ps.setInt(2, sale.getClientId().getClientID());
        ps.setInt(3, sale.getProductId().getProductID());             

        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void removeSale(int saleId) {
    try {

        String sql = "DELETE FROM sales WHERE saleId=?";

        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, saleId);
        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void editSale(Sale sale) {
    try {

        String sql = "UPDATE sales set client_id=? ,product_id=? where saleId=?;";

        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);


        ps.setInt(1, sale.getClientId().getClientID());
        ps.setInt(2, sale.getProductId().getProductID());            
        ps.setInt(3, sale.getSaleId());

        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public List getSales() {

    List saleList = new ArrayList();
    try {

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM sales";

        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {

            Sale sale = new Sale();  

            sale.setSaleId(rs.getInt("saleId")); 
            sale.setClientId(rs.getInt("client_id"));  
            sale.setProductId(rs.getInt("product_id");

            saleList.add(sale);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return saleList;
}  

public Sale getSaleById(int saleId) {

    Sale sale = new Sale();
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE saleId=?";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, saleId);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {

            sale.setSaleId(rs.getInt("saleId"));
            sale.setClientID(rs.getInt("client_id"));  
            sale.setProductID(rs.getInt("product_id"));

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sale;
}
```

}

Comment: do you have some error?

Comment: due to the getSales() method from SaleDAO im getting a Null Point Exception when accessing the viewSales.jsp also have encountered a second problem saying that cannot convert int to Client or to Product. I do believe it has something to do with the Sale bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ResultSet.getInt()` returns an `int`.

`sale.setClientID()` expects an argument of type `Client`.

And yet you're calling

```
sale.setClientId(rs.getInt("client_id"));
```

That can't possibly compile: an `int` is not a `Client`.

Your Sale class should not contain instances of Client and Product. Just like in the database row that a Sale is supposed to represent, the clientId should be an `int`, not a `Client`.

Or, if a Sale is supposed to represent a Sale, its client, and its product, your SQL query should return all of that information, and not just the ID of the client and the product. That's where joins are useful. A less efficient alternative would be to execute 3 queries: one that retrieves the sale, a second one that retrieves the client, and a third one that retrieves the product. And once all the information is available, you can finally create your Sale object and return it.

If you go that way, then please rename Sale.clientId to Sale.client: the attribute represents a complete client, not just the ID of a client.

Comment: thank you @JBNizet but I'm willing to represent a Sale with the client that's involved in the sale and the product/products brought by that specific client. This is the reason i wanted to use only the client and products id for such transactions.

Comment: That sentence is contradictory. Do you want a Sale object to only contain the ID of a client, or to contain itsID, but also its firstName, lastName, etc? If the former, then the Sale class shouldn't have a field of type Client, but a field of type int. If the latter, then your SQL query should retrieve the client information in addition to its ID.

Comment: i only want the Sale object to contain the Id of a client, not the entire info of that client. along side with the Id of a product included in that transaction. So in this case i should change the field type from Client to int? won't this change affect the FK in the sales table?

Comment: Yes, you should change the Sale class. Why do you think the code of your Sale class has any impact on the database schema? They are completely unrelated things. You create a class by writing code, and you define a schema by executing SQL queries. Writing Java code doesn't change a database schema.

Comment: Alright, seems to be working like a charm. Thank you very much for the help!